# how to make connection with crm on click of outlook send button

Tags: javascript, outlook, dynamics-crm, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I need to fetch details of organizer, subject and start time of new meeting on click of the **outlook send button**, and stored it into the crm tables.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Office web add-ins you can make [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) requests. The `Fetch API` provides an interface for fetching resources (including across the network). It will seem familiar to anyone who has used `XMLHttpRequest`, but the new API provides a more powerful and flexible feature set.

The [On-send feature for Outlook add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows) provides a way to handle a message or meeting item, or block users from certain actions, and allows an add-in to set certain properties on send, where you could also make a web call.

A lightweight launch events also can be considered, see [Use Smart Alerts and the OnMessageSend and OnAppointmentSend events in your Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/smart-alerts-onmessagesend-walkthrough?tabs=xmlmanifest) for more information. The `OnMessageSend` and `OnAppointmentSend` events take advantage of `Smart Alerts`, which allows you to run logic after a user selects `Send` in their Outlook message or appointment. Your event handler allows you to give your users the opportunity to improve their emails and meeting invites before they're sent. Be aware, the `OnMessageSend` and `OnAppointmentSend` events were introduced in [requirement set 1.12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/outlook/requirement-set-1.12/outlook-requirement-set-1.12).

See [Differences between Smart Alerts and the on-send feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/smart-alerts-onmessagesend-walkthrough?tabs=xmlmanifest#differences-between-smart-alerts-and-the-on-send-feature) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for quick response.
I have added the below code in manifest.xml file                                                    
 <FunctionFile resid="Taskpane.Url" /><ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events"><Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="addRecord" /></ExtensionPoint> and function is wriiten in html file and i am not able to debug the code, is there any way to debug what i am doing wrong on click of that send button.

Comment: I suppose that is a separate question for debugging the `ItemSend` event, right?

Comment: Thank you for your help.I have few doubts in that can please help me in that also:

 First I have followed the link but I don't understand one thing what change is needed in manifest file?second one is I have created launchevent.js file in the project I should modify the onMessageSendHandler function and in that function write code for connecting to crm right?

Comment: You can use the `ItemSend` event OR launch events depending on your needs.  Please post a new question in a new thread so users could easily recognize questions and answers.

Comment: I am using smart alerts, so when user click on new meeting then  in meeting the subject and organizer should get stored in crm, when send button is clicked, so for that OnMessageSend and OnAppointmentSend which event handler should I use? so that I will change in the lanuchevent.js file accordingly.

Comment: I am using the OnAppointmentSend event handler but it is showing add in isn't available at this time how I can debug the add in?

Comment: Thanks @EugeneAstafiev for providing the answer.
  OnAppointmentSend LaunchEvent can be used for a meeting and add-in can be configured for that as shown here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch?tabs=xmlmanifest.